# Objective C - frame.origin, frame.size

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, dynamic, position

I'd like to add buttons to a `UIScrollView` Vertically. It seems I can't get the starting point right:

```
int startPosition = self.view.frame.size.height/2 - self.view.frame.size.height/4;
```

that is the scroll view `frame.origin.y` ... the problem is that when i do:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(toolsScrollView.frame.size.width/8, startPosition, (toolsScrollView.frame.size.width*3)/4, (toolsScrollView.frame.size.width*3)/4);
```

the button is not added at the right place. In fact, even if i write 0 instead of startPosition, the button is added somewhere near the middle of the screen on the y axes. I can't figure out why? Are the frame.origin components absolute or relative to other objects?

Comment: i can not get you question.. please can you elaborate  it ?

Comment: Show the code you use to create the `UIScrollView` instance.

Comment: As you have it now, `startPosition` will be 1/4 the height of the scroll view (1/2 - 1/4 = 1/4) . Shouldn't the calculation be based on the content size and not the visible size of the scroll view?

Comment: BTW - A view's frame is always relative to its parent. If a view's origin is 0,0 it will be in the upper left corner of its parent, not the screen.

Comment: got it....frame .bounds ... two totally different things :)) ... didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

`frame` is relative to the coordinate system of the `superview`. Is is only a relevant detail when considering the `origin` however as that is all that is effected by the coordinate system.

Things to check:

1. What is the `frame` when your code is run
2. What is the `frame.origin` of the scroll view
3. What are the `contentSize`, `contentInset` and `contentOffset` of the scroll view
4. What inaccuracies do you get as a result of the integer division

Any one of these things can affect the visual position of your subviews